# How to animate an object with jquery using input type radio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this "block" and some radio inputs. When some of them is selected, I want to make the block move. However, the example I found for validate a radio input is using `$("input[name='objName']:checked"`. If I do this using `name`, the validation will not work (because all the inputs have the same name value). If I change each `name` then I can select all the inputs - which I do not want to.

HTML code

```
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <input type="radio" name="image" id="a1" class="input-task1"/>
                    <label for="a1" class="label-fase1"><img src="img/walk2.png" alt="2" class="img-form">Two (2)</label>
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="image" id="a2" class="input-fase1"/>
                    <label for="a2" class="label-fase1"><img src="img/walk2.png" alt="3" class="img-form">Three (3)</label>
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="image" id="a3" class="input-fase1"/>
                    <label for="a3" class="label-fase1"><img src="img/walk2.png" alt="4" class="img-form">Four (4)</label>
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="image" id="a4" class="input-fase1"/>
                    <label for="a4" class="label-fase1"><img src="img/walk2.png" alt="5" class="img-form">Five (5)</label>
```

jQuery code I found

```
    if ($("input[name='image']:checked")){
    let walk= 2;
    for (var start = 0; start < walk; start ++){
        $(".bloco").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use this jQuery logic but with ID? Other question is, can I put it into a function and call this function in a `onclick` for a button, so when I finish the questions I can run the function and animate the block?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: If you're using `input type='radio'` then each radio *should* have a different `value=`, so you could use `$("input[value=a1]").is(":checked")` - or `if ($("input[name="image"]).val() == "a1")` - otherwise just `$("#a1")` to use an id

Comment: @freedomn-m It didn't work. I don't know if I must put an onClick in my input submit or an onSubmit in the form tag to make it work, but I've tried all of your sugestions and nothing happened.

Comment: Your question, as asked and given the limited html and js, has the answer that you change `if ($("input[name='image']:checked")){` to `if ($("#a1").is(":checked"){`.   If that doesn't work, then your code/html don't match or there's some other issue.  Please provide a [mcve] with it *working* and then explain what you want to change.